Why does SeleniumBase in UC mode fail to find the driver path in a .exe built with PyInstaller?
I am using SeleniumBase in UC mode to launch a website. When I run my script as a .py file in PyCharm, it works fine. However, after converting it to an .exe file using PyInstaller and running the .exe, I encounter an error stating that the driver path cannot be found. This issue does not occur when I use standard Selenium, which works seamlessly in both .py and .exe modes.
I understand that SeleniumBase does not store the WebDriver locally, meaning I cannot manually specify its path. I suspect this might be the root cause, but I am unsure.
How can I resolve this issue?
This is my script:
    from seleniumbase import Driver
    import time

    my_user_dir = "C:/ProgramData/Dewbots/User Data/Chrome Data"


    # ############ LAUNCH BROWSER ############
    driver = Driver(uc=True, user_data_dir=my_user_dir, chromium_arg="--remote- 
                    debugging-port=7890")
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

    time.sleep(5)

This is the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tempfile3.py", line 8, in <module>
File "seleniumbase\plugins\driver_manager.py", line 789, in Driver
File "seleniumbase\core\browser_launcher.py, line 2765, in get_driver
File "seleniumbase\core\browser_launcher.py", line 4559, in get_local_driver
File "shutil.py" line 460, in copy2
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified
[PYI-13040:ERROR] Failed to execute script 'tempfile3' due to unhandled exception!

